# k8s run a job 5 minutes after the last was finished

Tags: kubernetes, cron, google-kubernetes-engine, jobs

I want to start a job every 15 minutes, but after the last one finished. I cannot use a cronjob as the next one starts after last one was started and not after last one finished.

with cronjob only this is possible when I use 15 minutes interval

- first run at 9:00 -> runs about 5 minutes
- second run at 9:15 -> runs about 5 minutes
- third run at 9:30 -> runs about 5 minutes

but what I want is the following:

- first run at 9:00 -> runs about 5 minutes
- second run at 9:20 -> runs about 5 minutes
- third run at 9:40 -> runs about 5 minutes

I do not want to use a "loop with a sleep in it" as job command because then the job would never stop running. The Job should complete its run so that the state of the job is "complete".

Comment: You cannot create dependencies between jobs using cronjobs the way you are describing it. cronjobs allow you to schedule jobs to run on a specific time. For what you are asking you will need some sort of external Job Orchestrator. Something like Airflow (or Cloud Composer which is the managed version) or maybe Google Cloud Workflows.